# ASP.NET Core identity is not sending e-mail

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

In my `Startup.cs` I have

```
services.AddTransient<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender, EmailSender>(i =>
    new EmailSender(
        Configuration["EmailSender:Host"],
        Configuration.GetValue<int>("EmailSender:Port"),
        Configuration.GetValue<bool>("EmailSender:EnableSSL"),
        Configuration["EmailSender:UserName"],
        Configuration["EmailSender:Password"]
    ));
```

and I have a class

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    /* snip */

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
    {
        var client = new SmtpClient(_Host, _Port)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _Password), EnableSsl = _EnableSSL
        };

        return client.SendMailAsync(
            new MailMessage(_UserName, email, subject, htmlMessage) { IsBodyHtml = true }
        );
    }
}
```

I'm running `smtp4dev`.

When I try to register a user or forget a password no e-mail is sent. In a breakpoint in `SendEmailAsync` is not hit.

I don't understand what I need to do to get this thing to send an e-mail.
Do you? And if so then can you tell me what it is?
Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: are you sure you inject IEmailSender somewhere and invoke method SendEmailAsync?

Comment: I've got an `IEmailSender` and registered it in `Startup.cs` but the code isn't hit and no e-mail is sent. I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: you should manually insert code to send email, it does not do it automatically

Comment: Shot in the dark, but what version of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` are you using?  Check your csproj file?   There is a known bug with version 3.04 where it won't hit the startup.cs file.  If that's you, downgrade to 3.03 or up to 3.05

Comment: @YegorAndrosov doesn't `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` automatically call the `IEmailSender` when user click reset password? if not, why does ui say 'Please check your email to reset your password.'?

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain emails are not being sent for both email verifications and password resets, then please ignore this suggestion. However, if your emails get sent for email verifications but don't get sent for password resets, then please read on.

Does a break point in the constructor of your IEmailSender get hit? If so then make sure that the user you're trying to reset the password for has a verified email address. If an email address is not verified Identity will not send any of the other email notifications.

Alternatively, temporarily disable confirmed accounts and see if your emails are being sent.

```
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
                {
                    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
                })
```

Comment: I confirmed that password reset will only send if EmailConfirm field in dbo.AspNetUsers is set to True. If the value is false then no reset email is sent when using the DefaultUI. Here is the code (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/ForgotPassword.cshtml.cs): if (user == null || !(await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
                {
                    // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                    return RedirectToPage("./ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
                }

Answer (score 0):

Please do add the code snippet where and how you are using EmailSender class ,  since you have asked for the documentation , which you can refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

Comment: In that documentation: how on earth do they get the database tables to be created? They don't go through creating a migration and running `Update-Database`.

Comment: > the admin account is created when the DB is seeded
This is not true.

Comment: And what is this `Seed` method? It's really annoying that they don't say what class and file it's in. I don't have one (what have I done wrong?) and I don't know where it's supposed to be.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough your question is about email sender and this article covers it.